# OCI response returns a list object with one entry

Tags: oci-python-sdk

The response.data attribute seems to return a Python list type object, with just one entry. To get the response data into a Python dict object I have to strip out the list contents before using the json.loads function. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
import oci
import json

myresp = core_client.list_instances(compartment,display_name="myinstance").data
# myresp is of type LIST
# Strip out contents of the list
myresp_list_contents = (myresp[0])

# Convert valid JSON string to Python dict
mypyth = json.loads(str(myjson_list_contents))
print(my_pyth['shape'])
# Script succeeds, mypyth is of type DIR as expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to retrieve data on only a single instance.

`list_instances` is meant to return a list of instances, hence why the returned object is a list.

If you are trying to retrieve data on only a single instance, I recommend using the `get_instance` API. Since this API is designed to return only a single instance, the returned object won't be a list, and so won't require you to index into the list to get the instance's data.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. But one disadvantage of `get_instance` is that you have to supply the instance ID, rather than the more user-friendly display_name.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But even `list_instances` takes an ID -- its just the compartment's ID instead of instance's ID. So either way you have to pass an ID

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. But stuff like the compartment ID is in my `~/.oci/config` file. Easy to access from a script running on my Linux client. I hate having to type in those long ID strings.